# AJAX sending PHP a variable to process issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a script that is sending data to a PHP file when the user clicks on an , but it's not working properly..

Here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.rve_button a').click(function(){
        console.log("You clicked it");
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax(
          type: "POST",
              url: "/wp-content/themes/vantage-child/parts/deleteticker.php",
              data: "id="+del_id,
              success: function(msg){
                 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
          });
         });
        });
});
```

The HTML & PHP:

```
if ($vars['watch']) { 
     echo "<td class=\"rve_button\">
             <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"".$stocks[$searchresults]['ticker']."\" class=\"delete tooltip\" title=\"Remove from this watch list\">
                <i class=\"icon-remove\"></i>
             </a>
           </td>\n"; 
}
```

The error being returned is this:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

What is wrong with my ajax call? Why would it be throwing this error? If it matters, this is in Wordpress.

Comment: you have additional `)};` in your jQuery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an opening { for the first parameter of $.ajax().
And then you need to add a closing } for the function that is the value for 'success'.

So...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-content/themes/vantage-child/parts/deleteticker.php",
    data: "id="+del_id,
    success: function(msg) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: You're the man! Thank you.. One question though, is that url: "" the correct way to send the data to the file? Right now the browser is throwing this error: POST (url to file) 500 (Internal Server Error).. Any idea how to fix this? Also, I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes when SO lets me.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error, it's most likely something wrong with your PHP script.  Check the result in the network inspector and see if it shows the php error (otherwise you'll need to check your logs)